# Call overloaded function from specific toolbox in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have some Matlab-Toolboxes installed. In my Matlab version one of the Toolbox-Functions collides with another. In this case it is hessian. I want to use the hessian function of the symbolic-Toolbox.

When in C/C++ Functions are multiple defined like the function for cos and I still want to use the “standard” cos-function I can write:

`std::cos(x);`

Is there something similar in matlab?

Comment: If you call `hessian` with a symbolic input, the Symbolic-Toolbox version of `hessian` will get called. Isn't that enough for your purposes?

Comment: No because i have the symbolic toolbox and the toolbox called intlab. When I type help hessian I get the help description of the intlab version but I want to use the symbolic one, if I just call `hessian` I get an error with not enough input argument because the intlab hessian wants more input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a very similar  way that you were describing for c/c++, you can use a specific toolbox function by adding the name of the toolbox first : `ToolboxName\function2call()`

First use the [`which`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/which.html) command to make sure of which function from which toolbox will be loaded with a specific call syntax.

Since I do not have the toolbox you are mentioning i'll use the classic `fopen` function as an example.

The first `fopen` function called without any other parameter will be the built in function which  is used to return a handle to a file. Indeed, the `which` command confirms that:

```
>> which fopen
built-in (C:\TLAB13a\toolbox\matlab\iofun\fopen)
```

Now let's say I want to use the `fopen` function to open a serial port, I need to prefix the call to `fopen` with the name of the toolbox/object, like so: `serial\fopen`. Let's first make sure this way of calling point to the right function:

```
>> which serial\fopen
C:\TLAB13a\toolbox\matlab\iofun\@serial\fopen.m  % serial method
```

Bingo !

And just to make sure this works when you are calling these functions, let's call them for real (with dummy parameters):

```
>> fopen('toto')
ans =
    -1

>> serial\fopen('toto')
Error using serial (line 72)
The PORT must be specified.
```

It worked. The first simple call to `fopen('toto')` return `-1` because it couldn't find a file named "toto".
The second call to `serial\fopen('toto')` errored because the serial port was not defined, but the right function was called.

---

Edit:
You can also override the order in which Matlab will fetch functions by re-ordering the Matlab path. If you put the symbolic toolbox before the other one in your path, then when called without explicit information, Matlab will execute the first function it finds in the path.

I would still recommend the first solution with explicit declaration though, because changing the path order could mess up other function call in case you have many overloaded functions.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. Your answer works perfect for me. Also your edit explains why the function of the other toolbox gets called and appears in the help description.

Comment: -1, This does not work (at least for R2012a). serial\fopen('toto') calls the serial and fopen function separately and attempts to divide the result!!
Your statement "The second call to serial\fopen('toto') errored because the serial port was not defined, but the right function was called." is totally wrong, because from the error message it is clear that the function "serial" has generated the error (and not fopen). It would be nice if this trick would work, but also the documentation seem to mention nowhere that the syntax with "\" is actually valid. serial\fopen('com1') also gives the error.

Answer (score 3):

If you have overloaded methods and want to call the built in one, you can use the function `builtin`. From the [official documentation](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/builtin.html):

> `builtin(function,x1,...,xn)` executes the built-in function with the
>   input arguments x1 through xn. Use builtin to execute the original
>   built-in from within a method that overloads the function. To work
>   properly, you must never overload builtin.

The syntax for using it is:

```
[y1,...,yn] = builtin(function,x1,...,xn)
```

<sub>Friendly advice: If you want to try overloading builtin ("hmm, I wonder what would happen"), remember to save stuff first.</sub>

Comment: I tried it, it won’t work. Becouse like I said my problem is the ‘hessian’-Funktion from the symbolic-Toolbox. Writing `builtin(‘hessian’, f)` gives me the error back that he cannot find builtin function ‘hessian’.